# get a part of string from multiline/column string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, substring

Application .net C#
I have problem how to get out (on button click) this (rounded red) value from  lista.txt file. In a fact, that's a exchange rate list. Values are changing daily.
Mine is always on the same position.
[image]

So far, using line.substring I've got the whole column inline:
5,2599355,3058300,2770031,0057322,4095196,1123050,8419020,7941597,0027418,7470806,926223**7,479628**1,729514

How do I get just a bold part. Its near end of string (7,479628).
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add the code written so far to reach the required line

Answer (score 1):

[String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) should be able to do what you want.

if you already have the column it would be:

```
var array = column.Split('\t'); //assuming the separator is a tab
```

Answer (score 0):

In the image it looks like the lines are tab seperated? 
You could read each line then perform a split using the tab character....

```
string[] arsplit = line.Split('\t');
```

and then grab the item from the array based on index which I presume you'll know

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"lista.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            int lineCount = 0;
            string inputline = "";
            do while((inputline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if(++lineCount == 13)
                {
                    string[] inputArray = inputline.Trim().Split(new char[] {' ','\t'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    Console.WriteLine("Exchange Rate : '{0}'", inputArray[2]);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just received solution that works fine from one guy. His suggestion was to check for EUR which I'm interested for. So, after downloading file, approach is:

```
        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fullPath);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (counter == 0)//jump first row, it's header don't need it
            {
                counter++;
                continue;
            }
            if (line.Contains("EUR"))
            {
                line = line.Replace(" ", "");//clean spaces
                line = line.Substring(3 + 3 + 3 + 8, 8);
            Response.Write(line);
            }

            counter++;

        }

        file.Close();
```

So it maybe it can be useful for someone. In this moment I don't know which of your solutions is best. Just want to thank  to all of you for help me in so short time.